# Azurite doesn't work with Blob Trigger in VS Code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azurite

I have created a function to run locally, I am able to do it for HTTP Triggered functions, but when it comes to BlobTriggered I am always getting the same error.

I am using Azurite for mocking the Blob Service in Azure at the http://127.0.0.1:10000 endpoint
The code I have is as follows:

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

The C sharp code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class BlobTriggerCSharp1
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create the new file on the Microsoft File Azure Storage on the container:

**local-emulator -> Blob Containers -> samples-workitems -> create a new item**

So always when I run after sometime I get the error bellow:
Functions:

```
        BlobTriggerCSharp1: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2021-05-06T11:29:19.279Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000182E0241'.   
[2021-05-06T11:29:47.002Z] An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down.
[2021-05-06T11:29:47.003Z] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Net.Http: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Private.CoreLib: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

**EDIT**

When I have tried to access the local storage account using Azurite from a local Azure Function

```
        var connection = new 

Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/test123");

try {
            BlobContainerClient client = new BlobContainerClient(connection,
                                                 new DefaultAzureCredential());

            await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in client.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            }
```

When callnig `client.GetBlobAsync` I get the error:

**"Cannot use TokenCredential without HTTPS."**

**EDIT2**

The way I did that made it work was by following this tutorial: https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/04/local-azure-storage-development-with-azurite-azuresdks-storage-explorer/

But I wasn't able to setup the Azurite extension of Visual Studio Code to work with it. I needed to do it in a separate command line and needed to do it through https.

Comment: COuld you please tell me if you can connect Azurite  via storage explore?

Comment: yes, I can connect, if you click on open connect dialog on the right and choose the localstorage emulator I think it connects to Azurite: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#storage-explorer

Comment: Have you tried to use the connection string to connect in your function app?

Comment: @JimXu I updated with more information, for some reason I am not able to access the local blob storage with a local azure function. It requires https, I am trying to follow this tutorial to fix it: https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/04/local-azure-storage-development-with-azurite-azuresdks-storage-explorer/ And will keep you updated

Comment: You also can use the access key to access it.